# Присвоить стороннему процессу все ядра CPU

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET, использую myProc(0).ProcessorAffinity = New IntPtr(1)

Если ранее с помощью ProcessorAffinity было задано одно конкретное ядро CPU, то как назначить все (как было по умолчанию)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Dim mask As IntPtr = New IntPtr((1L << Environment.ProcessorCount) - 1)
myProc(0).ProcessorAffinity = mask
```

Источник информации: [`Process.ProcessorAffinity Property` на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The default depends on the number of processors on the computer. The default value is 2<sup>*n*</sup> − 1, where *n* is the number of processors.

Но проще и правильнее, наверное, сохранить значение перед присвоением единицы, и восстановить его потом.

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Должен признаться, что я находил упоминания о маске, но не нашел примеров для более чем 1 ядра.